# Send a Mail from SQL server with attachment ( Attachment to be formed dynamically)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to send the report to management every morning . For that i have create schedule in Sql Server agent with following code.

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@recipients='bishnu.bhandari@gmail.com',
@body='Dear sir, <Br>Please find the attachment. <P>Regards<Br> <Br>IT Department', 
@subject ='TOURISM-GL( Auto By System) ',
@body_format = 'html',
@profile_name = 'emailserver',
@file_attachments='C:\PUMORI_NEW\**001_TOURISMGL_(14072014)_(SOD).TXT**'
```

Now the problem is, the file which i need to send as attachment will generate every day with new name. 
File name will be in format

> 001_TOURISMGL_(14072014)_(SOD).TXT

In above file name only the date value will be change. The date will be in ddmmyyyy format.

Now Kindly suggest me how can i achieve this. How send mail automatically with attachment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try,

```
declare @pathname varchar(200) = 'C:\PUMORI_NEW\**001_TOURISMGL_(,' + REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),101),'/', '') + ', )_(SOD).TXT**';

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@recipients='bishnu.bhandari@gmail.com',
@body='Dear sir, <Br>Please find the attachment. <P>Regards<Br> <Br>IT Department', 
@subject ='TOURISM-GL( Auto By System) ',
@body_format = 'html',
@profile_name = 'emailserver',
@file_attachments=@pathname
```

Comment: Corrected that. Could you try the new way?

Comment: With Some modification (date format 103 works for me) , it working now. Thank You very very much .

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be inside of SQL Server?  I do it with a batch file using BLAT (or Postie) with Windows Task Scheduler and SQLCMD (OSQL works too) and works just fine..

```
@ECHO OFF
@Rem -----------------------------------------------
@ECHO Procedure to e-mail daily Row Counts
C:
cd\reports

@ECHO Running database query, please wait
if not exist COUNTS.log osql -Sserver\instance -Uyouruser -Pyourpass -n    -iCOUNTS.sql     -oCOUNTS.log -w250

@rem ------------- Mail out report
if exist COUNTS.log Postie.exe -host:smtp.yourcompany.com -to:managers@company.com     -from:you@company.com -s:"Quick Counts for Session/Transaction/User" -file:COUNTS.log -msg:"Please reference below for the row counts for Session/Transaction/Users for DB1/DB2/DB3 Databases. This message was sent from %COMPUTERNAME%"

@for /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /T') do set dirdate=%%a.%%b.%%c
@if exist COUNTS.log copy COUNTS.log LogBkup\COUNTS-%dirdate%.log
@if exist COUNTS.log del COUNTS.log
rem @exit
```

Comment: I need to achieve this anyhow.I will try this and let you know. But i first preference is through sql server. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason you can't use the built in command, [xp_sendmail](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189505(v=sql.105).aspx)

It have just about every email option you are likely to want. It is sql 2005 or 2008. Older versions of sql, no such features, so people tended to use CDONTS (also by MS), but I would stay away from CDONTS if you have SQL 2005 or higher.

ADDED (accidentally posted prematurely)

In fact, if you have 2008 or above, you should not use xp_sendmail either (ha, misdirection) -- The new solution is [Database mail as documented here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175887(v=sql.105).aspx) This uses the stored proc xp_send_dbmail() -- note that this is NOT enabled by default, but the article tells you how by using the [DataBase Mail Configuration Wizard](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175951(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: i Was really unknown about command xp_sendmail since i am used to with above code. I will Try and let you know. Thank You very much for information.

Comment: Use xp_send_dbmail if you can